# Hibernate persitantBag class not found

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, tomcat

While I am trying to deploy war file in tomcat 7, an exception occur everytime as **java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.collection.PersistentBag**.

Although I am using hibernate 4.3.2 jar file and this class is in some other package (inside org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag) in this new version of hibernate jar file.

Can any one please let me know why it is searching file in this package?
Also I have checked my pom file and there is no file related to older hibernate version.

Here is the stack trace :

```
Nov 18, 2014 4:17:08 PM org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager doLoad
SEVERE: ClassNotFoundException while loading persisted sessions: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.collection.PersistentBag
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.collection.PersistentBag
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.CustomObjectInputStream.resolveClass(CustomObjectInputStream.java:74)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1611)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1516)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1770)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1349)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1989)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1914)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1797)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1349)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:369)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.readObject(StandardSession.java:1595)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.readObjectData(StandardSession.java:1060)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.doLoad(StandardManager.java:282)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.load(StandardManager.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.startInternal(StandardManager.java:489)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5476)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:632)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1073)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1857)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:701)
Nov 18, 2014 4:17:08 PM org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager startInternal
SEVERE: Exception loading sessions from persistent storage
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.collection.PersistentBag
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.CustomObjectInputStream.resolveClass(CustomObjectInputStream.java:74)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1611)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1516)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1770)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1349)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1989)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1914)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1797)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1349)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:369)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.readObject(StandardSession.java:1595)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.readObjectData(StandardSession.java:1060)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.doLoad(StandardManager.java:282)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.load(StandardManager.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.startInternal(StandardManager.java:489)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5476)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:632)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1073)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1857)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:701)
Nov 18, 2014 4:17:09 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
```

Thanks 
Abhishek

Comment: Looks like you are missing some dependencies.

Comment: Thanks Darshan, but same code is running fine in my staging environment, but throwing exception in my prod environment.

Comment: Do you have deployed other applications in the same tomcat using older versions of Hibernate? Or does tomcat itself has an older version of Hibernate in its bin?

Comment: It' not about the code but the dependencies are seem to be missing.

Comment: Yes, dependencies are same in both environments. I am trying to deploying same war file.

Comment: @Allner Yes there are three more war files in tomcat and I have looked in all war files, all are using latest hibernate jar files.

Comment: one more thing to add, exception is coming while I am starting deploying war in tomcat. Although war deployed successfully and there is no issue afterward regarding functionality so far. But I need to find the reason of  this exception.